# (Java) Create new REST web services dynamically during runtime

Tags: java, web-services, rest, heroku, jax-rs

I am experimenting stuffs with web services, and I am thinking to create new web services during runtime. My idea is by creating new Java file with appropriate JAX-RS annotation, and making it executable as new web service available for my web app.

For example, I have localhost:8080/services as initial web service, upon executing some command, the new java file will be created with localhost:8080/services/time as the new path for a new web service. Is this possible?

Creating new java file is no problem, it even resides in the correct path. but is there any way to force the newly created java file to be compiled and working appropriately? or maybe, lets say if i deploy it in heroku, can i force it to redeploy with that new addition?

Comment: And who will call these dynamic service?

Comment: This idea would give most SOA architects a mild heart attack lol...

Comment: You should take a look at OSGi.

Comment: @Dhawalk it would be the user who created that and anyone that they shared with. it is somewhat kind of service hosting concept. u give some code that abide my rules, and i will make that code available as a service. some information will be stored in database so user can check the service available. i dont know if this is practical in web service world or even java world. or maybe even programming world. to have codes that is not available to be available as part of the app later on.

Comment: @Namphibian well, it was just an experiment and I just want to know the limit of web service :)

Comment: @AndreiI i have made a quick look on it, and it seem interesting. i will study more on it after. but can it be deployed(the new addition) automatically by the app itself?

Comment: Not so easy. What you should to, is to have static service that receive dynamic parameters.... and eventually secured&validated :)

Comment: What you are trying to do is essentially writing your own service hosting environment. I don't have experience with heroku, but this is theoretically possible. I once laid a groundwork for this in WCF, But the project died because, there were no application to write and consume such dynamic services. That's the reason why i originally asked "And who will call these dynamic services"

Comment: @Dhawalk i see. well its part of my university project. they have made a component model that to me, is quite interesting and have the possibility to make it cross language if there is some framework that can handle it. and considering with the traits of the model, web service will be able to handle it. it is just this dynamic service question that made me wondering if it is possible. so you said u had basically done it before, do you have any advice on where i should look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do with Camel.  You'll need to register the objects, but it's possible.

Take a look here: http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html